# repetition of "for" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentence.

> This form is **for** your family member, who may qualify **for** "Allowance
> **for** Dependent".

I do not like repeating the preposition "for". The sentence sounds awkward.

In general, you should not repeat "for" in a sentence. Is that correct?

Comment: This is writing advice, not a matter of grammar. If you don't like the repetition, feel free to reword! And sure, excessive re-use of words can sound odd. But in my opinion "for" is such a small word and it only gets reused a second time, so it doesn't seem unpleasant to me.

Comment: More to the point: There's no rule that I'm aware of that you *must* not repeat words. "[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)" is a grammatically valid sentence. It's just darn hard to make any sense of.

Comment: This form applies to your family member.

Comment: The repetitions are far apart enough that I don't think anyone would notice them. Usually you try to avoid repeating the word consecutively.